# How do I run a command sql insert code in page load asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to copy many records from `profile_tb` to `Client_tb` without duplicate.
This code run in sql server very well but I don't know The following code is added to the client page load in asp.net.

Sql command :

```
iNSERT iNTO Client (ProfileID)
Select Distinct ProfileId From Profile Where Not Exists (Select 1 From 
Client where Profile.ProfileID = Client.ProfileID )
```

plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the SqlConnection, SqlCommand classes.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("your connection string")) {
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT iNTO Client (ProfileID) Select Distinct ProfileId From Profile Where Not Exists (Select 1 From Client where Profile.ProfileID = Client.ProfileID )", cn);

  cn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cn.Close(); }
```

I recommend you look into the SqlCommand more however and use the Parameters approach to defend against SQL injection attacks if this is website code.